# How to check if refresh token is expired with the SDK for iOS (Swift) - Amazon Cognito?

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-cognito, refresh-token

How to check if refresh token is expired with the SDK for iOS - Amazon Cognito?

Refresh token expiration day was set on Amazon Cognito.

I tried them after Refresh token expiration date.

```
user!.isSignedIn
user!.getSession().result
```

However it seems they don't work for checking refresh token is expired or not.

If you can give me any advice or tips, please tell me. I would really appreciate it. Thank you in advance.